# Multiple Google Analytics tracking ways - Mobile Web Application & Native app

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, web-applications, google-analytics

I've got an Mobile Web application with implemented Google Analytics tracking code - based on JavaScript code.

The next thing is that I've made an Android application that is actually a WebView that calls the URL address of that Mobile Web application and the Android application has implemented Google Analytics SDK for Android.

My question is:
Will Google penalize me if I track it on two-ways/multiple?

ex. If I lunch the Android Application, the activity starts, loads WebView (some URL).

Website has already got installed JavaScript GA tracking code (ex. profile xyz).
Android application got implemented GA SDK tracking code (ex. profile abc).

So, there are two different accounts/profiles for tracking:

1st one is for Website

2nd one is for Android SDK
 - multiple pageviews/visits

Sorry for my bad English.

Thanks for any information or help!

Best Regards.

Comment: Are you using the Native Analytics API for Android?: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/.

Comment: Yes, I do use Native Ga for Android (given from link).

Comment: What kind of penalization do you have in mind? Why would google penalize you for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has info page about installing multiple codes: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032400?hl=en

Also there is nothing in their Rules about not allowing to have multiple codes on you website or apps, I`ve been using multiple accounts for tracking one website and there were no problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter, Google wouldn't penalize you. Google Analytics is available for web sites and mobile apps. It's a good way for you to track different apps with different analytics code.